# (...) Show that $f(x) ≤ f(b)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$ and that $f(a) = f(b)$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Can someone help me with this proof?

> Let $a,b \in\mathbb{R}$ with $a < b$. Furthermore let $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous with the following conditions:
>
> 1. For $\forall x \in (a,b)$ there $\exists y \in (x,b]$ so that $f(y) > f(x)$.
> 2. For $x=a$ the first condition (1) is not fulfilled.
>
> Show that $f(x) ≤ f(b)$ for $\forall x \in [a,b]$ and that $f(a) = f(b)$.

Hints and solutions are both appreciated.

As suggested, I'm going to post my try here:

> To show: $f(x) ≤ f(b) \forall x \in [a,b]$
>
> $f$ is continuous $\rightarrow \lim_{x \to b}f(x) = f(\lim_{x \to b}x) = f(b)$.
>
> Now assume that $\exists x \in (a,b]$ so that $f(x) > f(b)$.
>
> Then there $\exists y \in (x,b]$ so that $f(y) > f(x) > f(b)$ using the first condition.
>
> However, it follows that $f(b) < \lim_{y \to b}f(y) = f(b)$, which is a contradiction.
>
> Hence $f(x) ≤ f(b) \forall x \in (a,b)$.

Is that OK?

Comment: Why you used a `(...)` in the beginning of the title of your answer?

Comment: I figured it would make sense since I left out the preconditions for this proof.

Comment: The statement of (2) is confusing. Does it mean to say that for all $y \ge a$, we have $f(y) \le f(a)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outline :

As $f$ is continuous, $f([a;b])=[c;d]$ for some $c$ and $d$. therefore $\exists x$ : $f(x)=d$. applying condition 1 to that $x$ would give a contradiction, therefore $x=a$ or $x=b$

if $x=b$, condition $2$ gives that $f(a)\geq f(b)$, and since $f(b)$ is the maximum...

if $x=a$, Assume $f(a)>f(b)$. then there exists $y$ close to $a$ such that $f(y)>f(b)$ (continuity). Then $f([y;b])=[m;M]$, and this time (using condition 1. again) the only choice is $f(b)=M$, witch contradicts $f(y)>f(b)$. Therefore $f(a)=f(b)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Assume that there exists $w\in[a,b]$ with $f(w)>f(b)$. Consider $x=\sup\{z\in[a,b]\mid f(z)=f(w)\}$. What is $f(x)$? If there is a $y\in[x,b]$ a promised by the first property, then use the Intermediate Value Theorem to reach a contradiction.